# Disable write access to Docker home directory

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

I am using a DockerSpawner for JupyterHub (image: jupyter/minimal-notebook). I mounted folder named "xyz" as /home/jovyan/xyz with all permission. I would like to disable write access to /home/jovyan in Docker, because I cannot guaranteed future access to data stored in Docker, only in host folder.

I tried to set up a read_only_volumes on /home/jovyan, but then is impossible to mount /home/jovyan/xyz

Any ideas please?
Thanks